# Error creating table with foreign key constraint using SQLAlchemy-Migrate

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

I'm building an app in python.  I'm using [sqlalchemy-migrate](http://packages.python.org/sqlalchemy-migrate/index.html) to track my database schema. I have a table, user_category, which has two columns: id and name.  I'm trying to create a user table with a foreign key to the user_category table.  My change script for creating the user table is as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from migrate import *
from migrate.changeset import *

meta = MetaData()
user_category = Table('user_category', meta)

user = Table('user', meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('email', String(255)),
    Column('first_name', String(40)),
    Column('surname', String(40)),
    Column('password', String(255)),
    Column('user_category', Integer, ForeignKey("user_category.id")),
)

def upgrade(migrate_engine):
    # Upgrade operations go here. Don't create your own engine; bind migrate_engine
    # to your metadata
    meta.bind = migrate_engine
    user.create()

def downgrade(migrate_engine):
    # Operations to reverse the above upgrade go here.
    meta.bind = migrate_engine
    user.drop()
```

When I run 'manage.py test' I get and error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedColumnError: Could not create ForeignKey 'user_catego
ry.id' on table 'user': table 'user_category' has no column named 'id'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You claim your "user_category" table has name and id. Definition of "user_category" contains no columns at all :)

Comment: It turns out to be this simple.  I thought that because the user_category table is defined in a previous change script then I didn't need to re-define it in the user change script.  I was wrong.  Thanks iElectric

Answer (score 4):

Instead of copy-pasting the definition of `user_category` table it is possible to tell SQLAlchemy to auto-load the table structure from the database:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from migrate import *
from migrate.changeset import *

meta = MetaData()

user = Table('user', meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('email', String(255)),
    Column('first_name', String(40)),
    Column('surname', String(40)),
    Column('password', String(255)),
    Column('user_category', Integer, ForeignKey("user_category.id")),
)

def upgrade(migrate_engine):
    _t = sa.Table('user_category', meta, autoload=True)
    meta.bind = migrate_engine
    user.create()
```

Sorry for the late answer :)

Comment: A useful answer is always welcome no matter how late it is :) Thanks!

Comment: I need define table after meta.bind assignment. After that it works. Thanks